# How to split a single column into multiple columns in SQL Server as data changes?

Tags: sql-server, split

I have an Event table which looks like below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Event](
    [EventId] [int] NULL,
    [Event] varchar(100) NULL,
    [EventDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ItemNo] [varchar](20) NULL
) 

GO

insert into [Event]
VALUES (1,'TestEvent','7/2/2015','Item1')
GO

insert into [Event]
VALUES (1,'TestEvent','7/3/2015','Item1')
GO

insert into [Event]
VALUES (1,'TestEvent','7/4/2015','Item1')
GO

insert into [Event]
VALUES (1,'TestEvent','7/5/2015','Item1')
GO

insert into [Event]
VALUES (2,'TestEvent02','7/7/2015','Item1')
GO

insert into [Event]
VALUES (2,'TestEvent02','7/8/2015','Item1')
GO

insert into [Event]
VALUES (2,'TestEvent02','7/9/2015','Item1')
GO

SELECT * FROM DBO.Event
GO

Event       EventDate   ItemNo
TestEvent   7/2/2015  Item1
TestEvent   7/3/2015  Item1
TestEvent   7/4/2015  Item1
TestEvent   7/5/2015  Item1
TestEvent02 7/7/2015  Item1
TestEvent02 7/8/2015  Item1
TestEvent02 7/9/2015  Item1
```

Now, I would like to split the Event field into multiple fields as the data changes, in this case, "TestEvent02" should appear as new field:

Please note that there can be multiple events so number of events is not fixed so number of fields to be generated should be dynamically calculated.

```
Output:
------

Event1       Event2     EventDate   ItemNo
TestEvent               7/2/2015    Item1
TestEvent               7/3/2015    Item1
TestEvent               7/4/2015    Item1
TestEvent               7/5/2015    Item1
            TestEvent02 7/7/2015    Item1
            TestEvent02 7/8/2015    Item1
            TestEvent02 7/9/2015    Item1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME(event)
  FROM (SELECT p.Event FROM dbo.Event AS p  
  GROUP BY p.Event) AS x;
SET @sql = N'
SELECT p.ItemNo,p.EventDate,' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
  SELECT p.ItemNo,p.EventDate,Event
   FROM dbo.Event AS p

) AS j
PIVOT
(
  max(Event) FOR Event IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p;';
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: It may be helpful for future users if you edit this answer to include more details about what is being done and how it works.  See [answer] for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much Gunjan, this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's bad idea. What the reason do you need to do this? I think, it's better to store events in one column, have index for selecting, or, maybe, have a partition table.

Comment: I would like to plot this on a charting tool and show events as different lines on the chart. I agree with you on the storage , so from that viewpoint, all events are stored in a single column, its just that I would like to have the output of SELECT in different columns so that my charting tool can show different graphs for different events.

Comment: @Abhijit Maybe you should select distinct event types and then select rows by every of this type

Comment: Yes, I can probably write a cursor to select distinct event types and build the required output but probably - a) that's not the best way to pull data , b) It wont be dynamic based on the number of events. I am trying to see if there is a better way to pull data using a single SELECT may be thru SQL Server PIVOT or other alternatives.

Comment: @Abhijit I don't agree with you, storing in different columns is bad idea. For every new type you'll ned to create new column. Better, add column EventType and select by this column

Comment: Hi Backs, just to clarify I am not storing the Events in different columns, as per the table definition mentioned above, the events are stored in a single column. Its just that the output from that table has to have different cols. for each of the events so that different lines can be plotted for each of the events on the charting tool.